# Get-ChildItem -File or -Directory doesn't work under different user context

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I have a PowerShell cmdlet with the following line

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderName -File -Force |
         Sort CreationTime |
         Select -First 1 -Last 1
```

It works fine under my normal login but if I log onto my machine as a domain admin I get an error message telling me that `-File` is not recognised as a valid parameter for `Get-ChildItem`.

I suspected that the domain admin was running an earlier version of PowerShell so under both accounts I have run `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` and get the following:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      0      10586  117
```

If anything I would expect my local login to fail and the domain admin login to succeed due to permissions differences but it seems to be working the other way around.

Comment: What's the location when you get the error? Are you actually on a file system path?

Comment: I have mapped a network share to my local workstation so the share appears as the Z: drive

Comment: Does the other user actually have access to that drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could Get-ChildItem somehow have been overwritten in your $profile or something else?

You can check what Get-ChildItem executes if you run this:

```
get-command Get-ChildItem

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Cmdlet          Get-ChildItem                                      3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
```

If it is overwritten by doing something like this:

```
Function Get-ChildItem { }
```

Then it will would show this:

```
get-command Get-ChildItem

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Get-ChildItem
```

If that would be the case, you can remove the custom version with

```
Remove-Item Function:\Get-ChildItem
```

You could also try to not use the -File parameter, and rather filter out folders yourself:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderName -Force | 
    Where PSIsContainer -eq $False |
    Sort CreationTime |
    Select -First 1 -Last 1
```

Comment: In both cases get-command Get-ChildItem reports Version 3.1.0.0 as per the first get-command example

Comment: I will try the Where PSIsContainer -eq $False method to get around this particular problem however my worry would be that if it is some version peculiarity I'll run into different flavours of the same issue.

Comment: I don't know what else can cause this to happen. If you want to get your hands dirty to try and figure out what is happening then it might be possible with "Trace-Command". Here is an article that goes over some usages of this command:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/12/04/trace-your-commands-by-using-trace-command/

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be resolved by ensuring that the PATH and PSModulePath variables are set to include the location of the ps1 scripts.

In this particular case the PATH and PSModulePath variable included the scripts location for the 1st user but not the 2nd user.

By correcting this the scripts ran successfully for the 2nd user login.